# How do I change css overflow property of a parent html element when hovering on a mega menu link

Tags: javascript, css

So I am using mega menu in my wordpress site and I need to change an element above the mega menu to have visible overflow css when hovering over a mega menu item. here is what I have tried so far.

```
      <div class="l-canvas">
        <div id="mega-menu-wrap-max_mega_menu_2" class="mega-menu-wrap">
         <div class="mega-menu-toggle" tabindex="0">
          <div class="mega-toggle-block mega-menu-toggle-block mega-toggle-block-right mega-toggle-block-1" id="mega-toggle-block-1">
          </div>
         </div>
        <ul id="mega-menu-max_mega_menu_2" class="mega-menu mega-menu-horizontal" data-event="hover" data-effect="fade_up" data-effect-speed="200" data-second-click="close" data-document-click="collapse" data-vertical-behaviour="standard" data-breakpoint="979" data-unbind="true">
          <li class="mega-menu-item mega-menu-item-type-taxonomy mega-menu-item-object-product_cat mega-menu-item-has-children mega-align-bottom-left mega-menu-flyout mega-menu-item-10217" id="mega-menu-item-10217">
<a class="mega-menu-link" href="#" aria-haspopup="true" tabindex="0">Link Text</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
       </div>
     </div>
```

And The css is pretty straightforward

```
 .l-canvas{
     overflow:hidden;
    }
```

The javascript is where I am having some trouble. Here is what I had working in a fiddle but cant figure out what is going wrong on my page.

```
$('.l-canvas').on('mouseover', '.mega-menu-item', function () {
    $('.l-canvas').css('overflow', 'visible')
});
//remove the overflow visible on mouseout
$('.l-canvas').on('mouseout', '.mega-menu-item', function() {
    // on mouseout, reset the overflow to hidden
    $('.l-canvas').css('overflow', 'hidden');
  });
```

I think I am close, but just cant seem to get over the final hump. I just don't understand why it wont work on my page or in console of developer tools. Thanks for any help and feedback you can give me on this issue.

Comment: Do you see any errors in the console? Have you tried adding console.log inside event handlers, are event handlers being called on mouseover mouseout?

Comment: The above js is as far as i have made it. I have not tried anything else because honestly I am a newb at this. :(

Comment: Well go ahead an open the console, search for red errors and if present google them! If no errors add `console.log('mouseover')` to your code and see what happens.

Comment: Ok i get the error TypeError: $ is not a function. I am getting this in console when trying to use my code above and the code suggested in the solution below.

Comment: Have you added jquery from a cdn using script tag?

Comment: Yes and I tested it to make sure it is loading using window.onload = function() {
    if (window.jQuery) {  
        // jQuery is loaded  
        alert("Yeah!");
    } else {
        // jQuery is not loaded
        alert("Doesn't Work");
    }
}

Comment: See how you are testing for jQuery variable and in your code you are using $, do the same test for $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(".mega-menu-item").on({
   mouseenter: function() {
      $(this).closest(".l-canvas").css('overflow', 'visible');
   }, mouseleave: function() {
      $(this).closest(".l-canvas").css('overflow', 'hidden');
   }
});
```

Have a look at the JQuery documentation for detailed information:

- http://api.jquery.com/on/
- https://api.jquery.com/closest/

First of all, you will want to listen to the events that occur when you enter or leave a menu-item. Next you will want to find a specific element up the DOM and manipulate the CSS of that element.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I am trying to test this code on my page, but I guess I am not sure how to utilize it correctly. I keep getting an error in console saying TypeError: $ is not a function. I am not sure how to go about fixing this to test it further.

Comment: Because of the jQuery-snippet you included in your question I thought you're already familiar with jQuery - jQuery helps you do some neat DOM-manipulation that would be rather tricky to do in pure JavaScript. Find an introduction here: [jQuery Get Started](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_get_started.asp) - you will first have to load jQuery somewhere in your HTML (in head or before closing body). After loading jQuery you can use `<script>$(document).ready(function(){ // CODE GOES HERE  });</script>` to wrap the code-snippet I posted in my answer.

Comment: Well I have jquery loading as part of revolution slider, but I went ahead and added the link to newest cdn minified version to before closing body, then the code you provided above after it. This makes the code work but now my revolution slider breaks. :) ahhhhhhh hahah i guess it is a jquery conflict?

Comment: Hm.. I can't tell about how this slider is implemented exactly and unfortunately there isn't much information about that on their website. It seems to make use of jQuery as well, though - so this should work together without problems. Anyway, make sure jQuery is included only once. Then place the snippet (including the information added in my previous comment) before your closing body tag.

Comment: Thanks  a million!

Comment: I was able to solve the conflict and get it all working by replacing the $ in your code to jQuery instead then it all played nice together. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: I'm glad to help!